# postgresql function data insert with python

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, function, insert

## my values

```
user = [[34, 'Victoria', '17:34:50', None], [40, 'Meherin', '00:04:00', '23:56:10'], [30, 'Micahle', '18:58:43', None]]
```

I have a postgresql function the name of merge_db() and it takes 4 argument. Now i want to insert value from user with python.

## postgresql function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_db(id1 integer, name1 character varying, login1 time, logout1 time) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the id
        UPDATE my_company SET (name, login, logout) = (name1, login1, logout1) WHERE id = id1;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- not there, so try to insert the key
        -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently,
        -- we could get a unique-key failure
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO my_company(id, name, login, logout) VALUES (id1, name1, login1, logout1);
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- Do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again.
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

## my python code such like

```
insert_query = "SELECT merge_db(%s) values %s"
execute_values(cur, insert_query, user)
conn.commit()
```

In this case throwing ValueError "ValueError: the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder"

I don't understand clearly that how to send user values as a merger_db argument.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: what version of postgres are you using?

Comment: my postgresql version 11.2

Comment: why don't you use `insert ... on conflict update`?

Comment: cause i have a RULE on this same table and that's why if i use conflict then i'm getting error simply.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in user:
        print(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], )
        insert_query = "SELECT merge_db({}, '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]
cur.execute(insert_query)
```

It'll work good but will raise error duplicate key error.